# Django, how to save User and model extended from User in 1 form?

Tags: python, django

I'm very new to Django so likely I'm missing something obvious here.
I have a model 'Profile' that extends form Django's User model. This model is for storing extra settings for the user which should be decided when registering. So I have a register form that I want to use to save a User and a Profile. Currently the User is created and the User's Profile is created but the Profile is not populated with the POST data in the registration form. I'm using signals but I must be missing a crucial component somewhere.

**models.py**

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    BUTTON_SIZES = (
        ('S', 'Small'),
        ('M', 'Medium'),
        ('L', 'Large'),
    )
    COLOUR_OPTIONS = (
        ('Def', 'Default'),
        ('Con', 'High Contrast'),
        ('Pro', 'Protanopia'),
        ('Deu', 'Deuteranopia'),
        ('Tri', 'Tritanopia'),
    )
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    teacher = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    button_size = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=BUTTON_SIZES)
    colours = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=COLOUR_OPTIONS)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Class, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile'
```

**forms.py**

```
class UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):

    BUTTON_SIZES = (
        ('S', 'Small'),
        ('M', 'Medium'),
        ('L', 'Large'),
    )
    COLOUR_OPTIONS = (
        ('Def', 'Default'),
        ('Con', 'High Contrast'),
        ('Pro', 'Protanopia'),
        ('Deu', 'Deuteranopia'),
        ('Tri', 'Tritanopia'),
    )
    button_size = forms.ChoiceField(choices=BUTTON_SIZES)
    teacher = forms.BooleanField(required=False)
    colours = forms.ChoiceField(choices=COLOUR_OPTIONS)
    # added to UserRegisterForm after creating Class model
    group = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Class.objects.all(),required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'password1', 'password2', 'teacher', 'button_size', 'colours', 'group',]
```

**views.py**

```
def register(request):
    if request.method =='POST':
        form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            messages.success(request, f'Account created for {username}!')
            return redirect('login')
    else:
        form = UserRegisterForm()
    return render(request, 'AppName/register.html',{
        'form': form,
    })
```

**signals.py**

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
        print("profile created")

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
    print(instance)
    print(instance.profile)
```

EDIT:
in forms.py I have the following imports

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from .models import Profile, Class, Simulation
```

In apps.py I have the following

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class AppnameConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'AppName'

    def ready(self):
        import AppName.signals
```

I now noticed that the last line is is greyed out. I've tried changing it around but I don't actually know what's wrong with it so I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: from where did you imported the `UserCreationForm` class?

Comment: I can imagine that the signals module is not getting imported in ready(). ref: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/signals/. Can you confirm ?